# Is there a way to identify indented text in a PDF using iText7

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

I'm using itext7 to parse a PDF and extract text from it. In a nutshell I call

```
var rawText = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0 i <= (LastPage > 0 ? LastPage : doc.GetNumberOfPages()); i++)
{
    PdfPage page = doc.GetPage(i);
    rawText.Add(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page));
}
```

to grab all the raw text from a PDF, then process and format the text to create something readable. However, with this approach I am unable to identify the beginning of paragraphs which in the original PDF is indented like so

```
   A beginning of a paragraph is indented like
this, but additional lines are not. 
   Further paragraphs within a page 
are all identified by indents.
```

Is there a way to identify the indents in the text and therefore where the paragraphs begin? Using the approach above, the indents are simply ignored.

Comment: Are you still interested in this topic?

Comment: @mkl Peripherally yes, but not actively

Answer (score 0):

For those wishing to extract text with added indents (PDF has none to speak aloud off) when extracting pages use -LayOut which will include extra space characters. and you can search for lines that have more space characters at start of lines.

Here using Xpdf to console but it could be a file. It is similar with Poppler utilities but the syntax for region of interest is different.

[image]
[image]

In such cases both have differences and merits with different degrees of additional controls, NOTE **the different injections of line feeds** (PDF generally has no line feeds), means Xpdf has separated the two paragraphs more, so worth testing both.